# Creating multiple lists in python or empty arrays

Tags: python

Hello I'm Just searching for a way to create multiple lists at once. by that I mean.

```
day1 = []
day2 = []
up to 7 days....
day7 = []
```

instead of having to copy and paste all the time and make my code look unprofessional and not looking good. I wanted to create a loop that creates these lists automatically.

Comment: instead you can use `dictionary`.

Comment: @El pupper This has much greater implications for your code than just looking  "professional". Selecting the right data structure is the key to writing good code. If your code uses day1, day2,....etc in different ways so that you cannot loop through them and you need all of these names in the global namespace then you have to declare them separately. Otherwise, it is almost always a good idea to create a nested list or a dict of list using one of the methods in the answers below.

Comment: thank you guys for the help <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

**1.** A basic list comprehension:

```
seven_lists = [[] for i in range(7)]
```

Which gives a nested list of seven lists:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

**2.** A list of `(day, [])` tuples:

```
days = [("day " + str(i+1), []) for i in range(7)]
```

Which gives:

```
[('day 1', []), ('day 2', []), ('day 3', []), ('day 4', []), ('day 5', []), ('day 6', []), ('day 7', [])]
```

**3.** A dictionary of days:

```
days = {"day " + str(i+1) : [] for i in range(7)}
```

Which gives:

```
{'day 1': [], 'day 2': [], 'day 3': [], 'day 4': [], 'day 5': [], 'day 6': [], 'day 7': []}
```

And then you can access/update each/multiple days like this:

```
>>> days['day 1']
[]
>>> days['day 1'].append(1)
>>> days['day 1']
[1]
>>> days
{'day 1': [1], 'day 2': [], 'day 3': [], 'day 4': [], 'day 5': [], 'day 6': [], 'day 7': []}
>>> days.update({'day 2': [1, 2, 3]})
>>> days
{'day 1': [1], 'day 2': [1, 2, 3], 'day 3': [], 'day 4': [], 'day 5': [], 'day 6': [], 'day 7': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use dict

```
dct = {}
for i in range(1,8):
   dct["day"+str(i)] = []
```

or dict comprehensions

```
dct = { 'day'+str(i):[] for i in range(1,8) }
```

output:

```
{'day6': [], 'day7': [], 'day4': [], 'day5': [], 'day2': [], 'day3': [], 'day1': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest way I can think of is this.

```
day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7 = [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer is correct. Someone downvoted every answer here.

Answer (score 1):

An odd way that is sometimes worthwhile is

```
from collections import defaultdict
days = defaultdict(list)
print(days['day1']) #prints [],
```

Doing this you can use whatever you like for day of week keys as long as you are consistent. Like

```
days['Monday']
```

or use number keys to make it look like an array.